# Confusing use of "seeing" and "having"

Tags: gerunds, progressive-aspect

I have two questions concerning 1. "seeing" and 2. "having."

**1.** Can "seeing" be used as a noun which might be modified by an adjective? Here's the example I am referring to: "**Star Trek Into Darkness is well ______ seeing.**" This example is taken from Cambridge English First Result, and I don't know what parts of speech are correct to use in the gap. I thought of "seeing" in this case as a noun which may be modified by an adjective.

**2.** What is the difference in the meaning of the following sentences?

**-** You smile a lot when you have a baby.

**-** You don't smile much when you're having a baby.

I appreciate every support and instructive pieces of advice. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The adjective "worth" is the obvious choice for gap since it licenses gerund-participial clauses, which is what "seeing" is. It's clearly a verb on two counts: it can be modified by the adverb "occasionally", but not the adjective "occasional", and it can head a passive VP like ".. is well worth seeing by all Trekkie fans".

Comment: Please, if you have two Questions separate them and Post each by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please always start two different threads for two different questions. This is because Wordreference is also used by others who may have the same question as you.

I'll answer 2. Please start a new thread for 1.

- You smile a lot when you have a baby. = You smile a lot when you have a baby in your life.
- You don't smile much when you're having a baby. = "You don't smile much when you are giving birth."

"having a baby" is an idiom that means "in labour" or "giving birth".

P.S. I don't really understand what you are asking in your first question.

Answer (score 0):

BillJ's comment gives the straight up correct answer regarding the specific example.

But I've just re-watched Carl Sagan's series Cosmos. Since he was an astronomer, he has a specialist term "seeing" which means the current conditions regarding the ability to make observations. As in "the seeing tonight is exceptional" indicating the air is still and clear. Or "a mountain observatory can provide better chances of good seeing." Or "a big city can create lousy seeing because of the light and pollution."